# How do I copy files with pscp to a non-home folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

Copying to the desktop and any other home folder works, but when I try to copy to a drive like `C:\file.txt`, it tells me "unable to open C:\file.txt: permission denied"

I'm using freeSSHd on the windows server, and  using NT authentication, so I'm logging in with the same user that I'm also logging in via remote desktop. When using remote desktop, I can(!) copy files to `C:\` or `D:\` simply with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Why not with pscp?

Desired commandline:

```
pscp -v -pw MyPassword C:/file.txt MyUser@ServerIp:C:/file.txt
```

Working commandline:

```
pscp -v -pw MyPassword C:/file.txt MyUser@ServerIp:/Desktop/file.txt
```

I already tried several variations with the slashes, forward, backward, double backward.. any advice on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the server using PuTTY or `ssh`, and use Windows `whoami/all` to check the privileges you have in an interactive SSH session.

Then check it again but **do not** open an interactive session this time; instead run `ssh yourhost whoami /all` or `plink yourhost whoami /all`, since batch and interactive sessions may get assigned different privileges. SCP uses the former.

Compare both outputs with the one you get when connecting over RDP interactively. It could be that Remote Desktop assigns more than freeSSHd – for example, it could be that the special `INTERACTIVE` group is not assigned when using SCP.

Comment: All three outputs show the same privileges: SeImpersonatePrivilege, SeCreateGlobalPrivilege, SeChangeNotifyPrivilege. For the INTERACTIVE and REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON groups it says "Enabled group" on all 3 tries.